# RFID-based access control system

Tags: arduino, spi, esp32, rfid, sd

I want to make a RFID-based access control system with an ESP32 and the Arduino IDE.

I found code from [electronoobs](http://electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut26_code1.php) and a video; it looks nice. I have tested it, and it works with the RC552.

When comparing a newly read card's UID with saved UIDs he uses this code:

```
//Compare the 4 bytes of the users and the received ID
 boolean compareArray(byte array1[],byte array2[])
{
  if(array1[0] != array2[0])return(false);
  if(array1[1] != array2[1])return(false);
  if(array1[2] != array2[2])return(false);
  if(array1[3] != array2[3])return(false);
  return(true);
}
```

This can be used with 4 users, but if I want to have 1000 users it won't work and my code will be very long. Are there any perfect methods for comparing more UIDs? It would be great, especially if there is code that can check from the UIDs stored on the SD card.

Comment: That code is not comparing 4 users, it is comparing the 4 bytes of a single user’s ID against the received 4 bytes.

Comment: Don't forget to compile your code, and save all your user's IDs (table 4 kbytes ?) into flash memory.

Comment: @HandyHowie Well i didnt say in anywhere this method comparing 4 users, i said that this method can be use for only 4 users but not 1000 users.

Comment: You need to explain why it can only be used for 4, since there is nothing obvious restricting it to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RFID-based access control system using an ESP32 and the Arduino IDE can be implemented by following these steps:

1. Connect an RFID reader to the ESP32 using the appropriate pins for
   communication.
2. Write the Arduino sketch to read the UID of the RFID card and store
   it in a variable.
3. Connect an SD card module to the ESP32 and write a sketch to store
   the UIDs of the authorized users in a file on the SD card.
4. In the sketch, use the SD.open() function to open the file and read
   the UIDs from it.
5. Compare the UID read from the RFID card with the UIDs stored on the
   SD card. If there is a match, allow access. If not, deny access.

To handle up to 1000 users, you can create a database of user information on the SD card, including their UID and any other relevant information such as their name and access privileges. You can then use the SD.open() function to read the database and check if the UID read from the RFID card is present in the database. This way, you can store and manage a large number of users efficiently.

It's important to note that the ESP32 has limited memory and processing power, so you may need to optimize your code and possibly use a more powerful microcontroller if you need to handle a very large number of users.

Here is an example of how you can implement an RFID-based access control system using an ESP32 and the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <SPI.h> // Include the SPI library
#include <MFRC522.h> // Include the MFRC522 library
#include <SD.h> // Include the SD library

#define SS_PIN 10 // Pin for the RFID reader's SS line
#define RST_PIN 9 // Pin for the RFID reader's reset line
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create an instance of the MFRC522 library

#define SD_CS_PIN 5 // Pin for the SD card's CS line
File uidFile; // File to store the UIDs of the authorized users

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize the serial monitor
  SPI.begin(); // Initialize the SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Initialize the MFRC522 library
  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS_PIN)) { // Initialize the SD card and check for errors
    Serial.println("Error initializing SD card");
    return;
  }
  uidFile = SD.open("uidList.txt"); // Open the file to store the UIDs of the authorized users
  if (!uidFile) { // If the file couldn't be opened, print an error message
    Serial.println("Error opening UID file");
    return;
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { // Check if a new card is present
    mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial(); // Read the card's UID
    byte* uid = mfrc522.uid.uidByte; // Store the UID in a byte array
    uidFile.seek(0); // Go to the beginning of the file
    while (uidFile.available()) { // Read the file until the end
      byte fileUid[4]; // Create a byte array to store the UID from the file
      uidFile.read(fileUid, 4); // Read the UID from the file
      if (memcmp(uid, fileUid, 4) == 0) { // Compare the UID from the card with the one from the file
        Serial.println("Access granted"); // If there is a match, allow access
        uidFile.close(); // Close the file
        return;
      }
    }
    Serial.println("Access denied"); // If the UID from the card is not in the file, deny access
    uidFile.close(); // Close the file
  }
}
```

This code will read the UID of the RFID card and compare it with the UIDs stored in a file on the SD card. If there is a match, it will print "Access granted" to the serial monitor and allow access. If not, it will print "Access denied" and deny access.

Comment: This answer appears to be wholly or largely AI based. Is it ? || Unlike some, this may be correct. I haven't checked in fine detail but at a skim it looks ok.

Comment: Real Prediction based on 82 tokens Real = 0.12% , Fake = 99.88%